# Remove repeated button and anchor tag from grouping rows and toggle in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a table which contains grouping rows(where Order no. is same those are grouping rows) and I want to add a button against each unique order no. anchor tag and on that basis I want to toggle expand collapse grouping rows:
[image]

I'm using below script but this is not correct:

```
function ToggleGroup(button) {
            var row = $(button).closest('tr');
            /*var group = row.nextUntil(':not(.grouped)');*/
            var group = row.nextUntil('tr:has(button .myButton)');
            group.toggle();
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dgFullOrdersView > tbody  > tr:first').find('td:eq(6)').before('<td></td>');

            $('#dgFullOrdersView > tbody  > tr').not(":first").each(function () {
                var ctl = $(this).find('td > #hypOrder');
                /*alert(ctl);*/
                $(this).find('td:eq(6)').before('<td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;"><button style="height:5px;width:5px;" id="btnToggle" class="myButton" onclick="ToggleGroup(this); return false;">+</button></td>');
            });
        });
```

This is my html markup:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="dgFullOrdersView" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
<--columns here-->
</tr>
<tr>
/*some columns here*/
<td>
                <a id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl03_hypOrder" class="mainnav1" 
                   onclick="LogOrderViewDetails(237851)" href="OrderResults.aspx?OrderNo=237851">237851</a>
             </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Kindly suggest how to implement this in jquery.